How to load and play m3u8 files on iOS in Flutter?
I got m3u8 files to play locally on Android, but it didn’t work on iOS. On iOS, it says the m3u8 files can’t be found, even though they are there. I checked, and the files really do exist. The m3u8 files are downloaded in a zip format, unzipped, and saved in the iPhone’s application support directory for offline use. Here’s my code:
BetterPlayerController? _betterPlayerController;
  String? _currentFilePath;
  final m3u8Files = [
    "videos/hls-rePInEf/144_20241203075239.m3u8",
    "videos/hls-futP2Q8/144_20241203075247.m3u8",
    "videos/hls-uRlc1u7/144_20241203075256.m3u8",
    "videos/hls-TY3rUyZ/144_20241203075304.m3u8",
    "videos/hls-cFpWWtU/144_20241203075313.m3u8",
    "videos/hls-7xU8XwX/144_20241203075321.m3u8",
    "videos/hls-aHN5sLS/144_20241203075329.m3u8",
    "videos/hls-yvzavUU/144_20241203075338.m3u8",
    "videos/hls-Fho4sXJ/144_20241203075346.m3u8",
    "videos/hls-JV3sGiE/144_20241203075354.m3u8",
    "videos/hls-Qir55am/144_20241203075403.m3u8",
    "videos/hls-2XO6goo/144_20241203075412.m3u8"
  ];

void _initializePlayer(String filePath) {
    _disposeController();
    debugPrint(filePath);
    String finalPath = filePath;
    if (!filePath.startsWith('file://')) {
      finalPath = "file:/$filePath";
    }
    debugPrint("Path: $finalPath");
    BetterPlayerConfiguration betterPlayerConfiguration =
        const BetterPlayerConfiguration(
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );

    _betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(betterPlayerConfiguration);

    _betterPlayerController!.setupDataSource(
      BetterPlayerDataSource(
        BetterPlayerDataSourceType.file,
        filePath,
      ),
    );

    setState(() {
      _currentFilePath = filePath;
    });
  }


Expanded(
  flex: 2,
  child: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: m3u8Files.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        String filePath = "${widget.dirPath}${m3u8Files[index]}";
    
        return ListTile(
        title: Text(m3u8Files[index]),
        onTap: () async {
          final directory =
              await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          final outputDir = Directory('${directory.path}/');

          debugPrint(
              !outputDir.existsSync() ? 'Not found' : 'Found');
          final finalPath = "${outputDir.path}${m3u8Files[index]}";
          final file = File(finalPath);
          debugPrint("Path: $finalPath");
          debugPrint("Exist: ${file.existsSync() ? 'Yes' : 'No'}");
          _initializePlayer(filePath);
        },
      );
    },
  ),
),


// logged
flutter: Found
flutter: Path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F6C6C89F-BC46-413B-8608-63326780EE14/Documents/videos/hls-rePInEf/144_20241203075239.m3u8
flutter: Exist: Yes
flutter: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F6C6C89F-BC46-413B-8608-63326780EE14/Documents/videos/hls-rePInEf/144_20241203075239.m3u8
flutter: Path: file://var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F6C6C89F-BC46-413B-8608-63326780EE14/Documents/videos/hls-rePInEf/144_20241203075239.m3u8
flutter: GetDataFromUrl failed: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F6C6C89F-BC46-413B-8608-63326780EE14/Documents/videos/hls-rePInEf/144_20241203075239.m3u8

How can I fix this for iOS? Thanks in advance
